# start websphere server from RAD hangs at "Server server1 open for e-business"

Tags: java, websphere, rad

I did the RAD set up recently and trying to *start websphere server*.

In the log, it hangs at the following line and get terminated after timeout:

```
Server server1 open for e-business
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you posted info about version and your environment information.

Comment: @Magnus: RAD version: 7.5; Websphere application server: 6.1; Windows 7 OS;

Comment: I had similar issue with WAS 7 on Windows 7, seems to be the installation path was too long, moved to c:/WAS solved the error. Also installation manager shows a warning on Windows 7 when installing WAS in my installation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.

In my case, I did following configuration which solved the issue and server started.

Double click on the server (in the servers tab). 
In **Server connection types and administrative ports** select **Automatically determine connection settings** and save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your workspace [folder/name could be the issue.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21460336)

the WAS installation itself. When moved it to C:\was8 everything started to work properly. The default puts it into c:\Program Files... and that was hanging at 23%

a. Please use websphere jre to replace sun hotspot vm to launch the eclipse, like below setting in the eclipse.ini

```
-vm
D:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/javaw.exe
```

b. Please make sure there is not a specail character (like 23%) in the websphere path or eclipse workpsace.

Comment: I faced the same problem starting the server in eclipse neon. How can I use WebSphere 8.5.5 JRE6 for eclipse neon, which only supports JRE8 or higher? What else could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the jar com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar from C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\runtimes
to C:\development\endorsed and in eclipse.ini add this just JVM param (under -vmargs)
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\development\endorsed